# Php even if passwrod is good form sow it's valid

Tags: php, pdo

I create a login format in php. But even if i pass correct password form do not work. I check in te iternet and it should work. i print my password1 and hash_password1 and it's show a good value, of correct hash and password.But is still show password is bad that my password that in the bad password.
I need write more that they cnapost my question it is not a lot of code

```
        <?php
        session_start();

        if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
            header("location: glowna.php");
            exit;
        }

        include 'polaczenie_baz_danych.php';

        $email = $password1 = "";
        $email_err = $password1_err = "";

        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

            if(empty(trim($_POST["email"]))){
                $email_err = "Wprowadz email";
            } else{
                $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
            }

            if(empty(trim($_POST["password1"]))){
                $password1_err = "Wprowadz haslo";
            } else{
                $password1 = trim($_POST["password1"]);
            }

            if(empty($email_err) && empty($password1_err)){

                $sql1 = "SELECT id, email, password1 FROM users WHERE email = :email";

                if($stmt = $db->prepare($sql1)){

                    $stmt->bindParam(":email", $param_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);

                    $param_email = trim($_POST["email"]);

                    if($stmt->execute()){

                        if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){
                            if($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                                $id = $row["id"];
                                $email = $row["email"];
                                $hash_password1 = $row["password1"];
                                var_dump($password1);
                                var_dump($param_password1);
                                $param_email = $email;
                                if(password_verify($password1, $hash_password1)){

                                    session_start();

                                    $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                                    $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                                    $_SESSION["email"] = $email;                            


                                    header("location: glowna.php");
                                } else{

                                    $password1_err = "Niepoprawne haslo.";
                                    var_dump(password_verify($password1, $param_password1));

                                }
                            }
                        } else{

                            $email_err = "nie ma takiego konta.";
                        }
                    } 



                }
            }

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: What's the length and charset of your password field.

Comment: longer than 6  and all mrks and specialmarks are  allow

Comment: What? It should be VARCHAR(255) utf8mb4

Comment: sorry yes it is

Comment: You are setting `$param_email` **after** using it. Swap the lines `$stmt->bindParam(...)` and `$param_email = trim($_POST["email"]);`

Comment: Show us polaczenie_baz_danych.php

Comment: please share your `password_verify` method

Comment: You are starting twice the session too

Comment: @cid Why would that change anything?

Comment: @RonakDhoot this is native to php

Comment: @RonakDhoot https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: @Dharman well, I just remembered that the order doesn't matter, one strange behaviour of php

Comment: @Dharma this is correct i can add my produc normal to database with any problem

Comment: `password_verify ( string $password , string $hash )`

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump(password_verify($password1, $param_password1));` ?

Comment: the output of var_dump(password_verify($password1, $param_password1))  :  string(12) "123456qwerty" string(50) "$2y$10$JCSndkZBkK1sREolgTQsremwGltQlssTGPkcF87jVjY"

Comment: This can't be. `password_verify()` should return a boolean value

Comment: this uoutput is :false

Comment: How did you hash the password ? Did you use `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` ?

Comment: The hash is too short for a password hash by 10 characters. Did you use password_hash when hashing the password?

Comment: yes  use it with password_hash

Comment: yes i use PASSWORD_DEFAULT and i change this to PASSWORD_BCRYPT and log form do not work

Comment: It looks like you didn't set enough space to store passwords. PASSWORD_DEFAULT  uses 60 characters and the shown dump is 50 characters long. They are truncated.

Comment: @Cid it is not the first time you mention the order of binding. It is never an issue.  This is how bind by reference works. First bind, then define.